# How to edit fields' values in the hook_node_load function?

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

In the `hook_node_load` function I want to alter a field's value.
I printed the node variable and got the following structure for the field:

```
    [field_myfield] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1316760775
                        )

                )

        )
```

So I should write something like `$node->field_myfield[und][0]['value'] = 'sth'`. My site has 2 available languages, and [und] will be changed when language is changed.
How can I alter the field value for all languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $node object will have its language in a language variable. So, create another variable to work with like `$lang = $node->language;`; then you can write `$node->field_myfield[$lang][0]['value'] = 'sth';`, where the language will be dynamic with the $node object.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with entity_metadata_wrapper(), see [this blog post](http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7) for more info on that.

```
$node = node_load(323);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$wrapper->title = 'New title for the node';
$wrapper->save();
```

It works for any property: title, fields, author, etc.

Comment: I guess the second line should be:
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);